# uploading file with a form from Flex Air to Java Servlet 3.0

Tags: apache-flex, post, air, flex4, servlet-3.0

I have been searching for days... I have a a Flex Air application that needs to upload a form to a java servlet. The form is extremely basic:

> First name:
>   Last name:
>    Picture:

It is the most basic application... I have been trying to use this on client side:

> http://blog.inspirit.ru/?p=139

```
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import ru.inspirit.net.MultipartURLLoader;

var data1:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
data1.writeUTFBytes("This is a test 1");
data1.position = 0;

var data2:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
data2.writeUTFBytes("This is a test 2");
data2.position = 0;

var ml:MultipartURLLoader = new MultipartURLLoader();
ml.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onReady);

function onReady(e:Event):void
{
    // Upload Complete
}

// simple string data
ml.addVariable('test', 'test variable');

// file data: ByteArray, File name, Name of the file field, content MIME type (default application/octet-stream)
// use [] if you need identical file field name
// specify MIME type for your file part
ml.addFile(data1, 'test1.txt', 'Filedata[]');
ml.addFile(data2, 'test2.txt', 'Filedata[]', 'text/plain');

ml.load('test.php');
```

On server side all I want to do is save the pic.jpg as lastname.jpg in a c:/uploads/

could someone show me the most basic working example between air and java servlet 3.0

Comment: Im not brave enough to click the link. Can you post some code?

Comment: and I think this work just fine... but I don't know how to save it on servlet side! on the server side I have a multipart post... i just need to save it in the right path with the right name!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "upload a form".  Do you mean you want to upload data?  Or just send data to your Java service? Is your Java service expecting data as AMF, SOAP, or REST?

Comment: form has 3 fields: firstname lastname and the pic in jpg format. I need to get all this in servlet. I need to do it with HTTP POST

Answer (score 2):

This may be somewhat outdated but it works - might give you a start:

```
public function buildForm() : void
{
    var requestObj : Object = new Object();
    requestObj.javavalue0 = value0;
    requestObj.javavalue1 = value1;
    flexform.request = requestObj;

    flexform.send();
}

<mx:HTTPService id="flexform" url="https://someurl.org/Form/servletPage" 
    method="POST" result="resultHandlerSubmitForm(event)" 
    fault="faultHandler(event)" />
```

---

On the java side: use `request.getParameter` to get the POST values.

```
public class servletPage extends HttpServlet
{

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code> methods.
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try
    {
        String str_javavalue0 = request.getParameter( "javavalue0" );
```

and so on....

Comment: yea.. but the problem is more on the servlet side!

Comment: What is the problem on the servlet side that is not addressed in this answer?  I think this answer shows how to use Flex to communicate with the servlet and how to access the passed parameters inside the servlet.  What else do you need?